# Eclipse JDT static field modifiers

Tags: eclipse, static, field, eclipse-jdt

I want to get the information about a field modifier. To be precise, I want to find out is the field a static one. For example, I want to examine the following code:

```
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
```

How can I infer that the **JLS3** is static field? I used *getModifiers* with *Modifier.isStatic* when analyzing methods and it worked fine. However, now I am not able to get the information that **JLS3** in above code snippet is a static field. Is there something I am missing?

EDIT:

This is the code that I am using:

```
private boolean visit(SimpleName name){
   boolean isStatic = Modifier.isStatic(name.resolveTypeBinding().getModifiers());
   ...
   return true;
}
```

*isStatic* is false in the case of **JLS3**.

Comment: getModifiers should work for both FieldDeclaration and MethodDeclaration. Can you post your code and the exact problem that you face, e.g. method call which is giving unexpected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's obviously wrong, use `name.resolveBinding()` instead of `name.resolveTypeBinding()` --- so you should get an object of type IVariableBinding.

`name.resolveTypeBinding()` returns the binding for the *type* of the field, but not the binding of field itself, which is not what you want here.